# how to get Different name for each td?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help, what should I do so that all the rows have each one a different id for example:introdu1,introdu2,introdu3

```
var perrow = 1; 
array.forEach((value, i) => {

  myTable += `<td id="ore">${value}</td>`;
  myTable += `<td id="introdu" > </td>`;
  
  
  var next = i + 1;
  if (next%perrow==0 && next!=array.length) { myTable += "</tr><tr>"; }
});
```

Comment: Just use class names instead and you won't need to generate a unique id for each one. Why do you feel you need these ids?

Comment: Tables should not contain ids at all. What is the problem you're trying to solve with ids?

Comment: Try changing `id="introdu"` to `id="introdu${i+1}"` to generate unique id's ..

Comment: Again: ids in a table are useless, specifically in a dynamic table. You're getting a id-nightmare if rows are removed from the table. If you want to refer a cell numerically, tr elements have rowIndex, and td elements have cellIndex, both being updated automatically when the table changes.

Comment: Hmm ... it looks like the mentioned nightmare has already started.

Comment: ok thank you for help guys now I know what to do :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a dynamically generated ID:

```
var perrow = 1;
var id = 1;
array.forEach((value, i) => {

  myTable += `<td id="ore${id}">${value}</td>`;
  myTable += `<td id="introdu${id++}" > </td>`;

  var next = i + 1;
  if (next % perrow == 0 && next != array.length) {
    myTable += "</tr><tr>";
  }
});
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You can't repeat the id on the first `<td>`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Meant `id++`.

Comment: `id="ore"` is repeated

Comment: @Keith if I pre-increment, the first td would have an id of 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy you can use `${variable}` like you do in `${value}`

```js
let array = ['r','4','6'];  
let myTable = "";
var perrow = 1; 
    array.forEach((value, i) => {
    var next = i + 1;
    
      myTable += `<td id="ore${next}">${value}</td>`;
      myTable += `<td id="introdu${next}" > </td>`;
      
      if (next%perrow==0 && next!=array.length) { myTable += "</tr><tr>"; }
    });
    console.log(myTable);
```

```css
td {
background : red;
}
```